# How to add items from one list to another?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list1 in python as listed below:

ls1

```
['A', 4, 'M', '1', 128.2, 169.818, '2019-02-27']
['B', 4, 'M', '1', 169.818, 172.3, '2019-02-25']
```

ls2

```
['2019-02-27','2019-02-25']
```

When I am trying to add another date item from another list, it is not adding as a part of each row in list rather it is adding as a seperate component like below:

ls3

```
['A', 4, 'M', '1', 128.2, 169.818, '2019-02-27'],
'2019-02-27',
['B', 4, 'M', '1', 169.818, 172.3, '2019-02-25'],
'2019-02-25'
```

I would rather needed ls3 as:

```
['A', 4, 'M', '1', 128.2, 169.818, '2019-02-27','2019-02-27']
['B', 4, 'M', '1', 169.818, 172.3, '2019-02-25','2019-02-25']
```

Comment: Show code that you used to get this first (wrong) result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
ls1 = [['A', 4, 'M', '1', 128.2, 169.818, '2019-02-27'], ['B', 4, 'M', '1', 169.818, 172.3, '2019-02-25']]
ls2 = ['2019-02-27','2019-02-25']

new_ls1 = [l1 + [l2] for l1, l2 in zip(ls1, ls2)]
```

A more hack-ey way (not faster, use the first one!):

```
new_ls1 = list(map(list, zip(*zip(*ls1), ls2)))
```

Or, if you would like, you can operate in-place:

```
for i, item in enumerate(ls2):
    ls1[i].append(item)
```

Comment: Please give the OP time to at least show their attempt first. Otherwise you're cheating them the opportunity to learn to create their own code and not motivating them to improve their question up to site standards.